# Dynamic cast and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast

The `dynamic_cast` operator is returning zero (0) when I apply to a pointer that points to an instance of a multiply inherited object.  I don't understand why.

The hierarchy:

```
class Field_Interface
{
  public:
    virtual const std::string get_field_name(void) const = 0; // Just to make the class abstract.
};


class Record_ID_Interface
{
  public:
    virtual bool has_valid_id(void) const = 0;
};


class Record_ID_As_Field
: public Field_Interface,
  public Record_ID_Interface
{
// This class behaves as a Field and a Record_ID.
// ...
}


// A demonstration function
void Print_Field_Name(const Field_Interface * p_field)
{
  if (p_field)
  {
    cout << p_field->get_field_name() << endl;
  }
  return;
}


// A main function for demonstration
int main(void)
{
  Record_ID_As_Field *  p_record_id = 0;
  p_record_id = new Record_ID_As_Field;
  if (p_record_id)
  {
     // (1) This is the trouble line
     Print_Field_Name(dynamic_cast<Field_Interface *>(p_record_id));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I want to have the `Record_ID_As_Field` to be treated as a `Field_Interface`, but also fit in where `Record_ID_Interface` are required.

Why is `dynamic_cast` in (1) above returning 0, and how do I resolve this?

I am using Visual Studion 2008 on Windows XP.

*Note:  For simplicity, I am using fundamental pointers in this example.  Actual code uses `boost::shared_ptr`.*

Comment: There's no reason to test that `p_record_id` is not null, `new` never returns null. (And I'll assume it's because it's a snippet, but make sure your public base classes have virtual destructors.)

Comment: i always thought dynamic cast if for upcasting ..  and that downcasting is implicit...

Comment: There's no evidence that you implemented the abstract methods.  Did you?

Comment: @Vardhan: upcast (from derived to base) is automatic, downcast (from base to derived) requires an explicit cast.

Comment: Oh, and your code is correct, the `dynamic_cast` should not be returning 0. You "fixed" the problem in transit from real-problem to question-problem.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: You better provide the real code, as the code you have provided compiles without problem. Note that there is no relation among distinct instantiations of shared pointers, that is `shared_ptr<derived>` is unrelated to `shared_ptr<base>` and cannot be used polymorphically

Comment: Not so related to the problem but still, If you're creating classes that inherit from each other, You MUST declare a virtual d-tor or else you will have leaks.

Comment: Why return a `const string` by value?  Seems kinda rude.

Comment: @GMan:  Testing for null is a C language habit from embedded systems world.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, abstract methods are implemented, removed from example (along with virtual destructors) for brevity.

Comment: I will "boil down" the actual code to see what the issue is.  If problem still occurs, I will have an actual example for all of you.

Comment: Print_Field_Name() really ought to take a "const Field_Interface &" instead of a pointer...

Comment: @Thomas: This isn't C, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: For simplicity, I am using fundamental pointers in this example. Actual code uses `boost::shared_ptr`.

And that's your problem right there: You cannot `dynamic_cast` a `shared_ptr<A>` to a `shared_ptr<B>` since those two types are not actually related to each other, even if `A` and `B` are.

Luckily in the specific case in your question the `dynamic_cast` shouldn't be necessary, since `Record_ID_As_Field*` should be implicitly convertible to a `Field_Interface*` (since the one is derived from the other). `shared_ptr` implements conversion operators that lift these implicit conversions to the respective `shared_ptr` objects, so `shared_ptr<Record_ID_As_Field>` should be implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<Field_Interface>`.

If you leave out the `dynamic_cast`, it should work.

If you'd actually need to do a dynamic cast, you could use a [special constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors) provided by `shared_ptr`:

```
shared_ptr<Record_ID_As_Field> raf;
shared_ptr<Field_Interface> fi(raf, dynamic_cast<FieldInterface*>(raf.get());
```

<sub>(I'm not sure what would happen there if the `dynamic_cast` fails, so you should investigate what's the best way to handle that situation.)</sub>